# ajax and relative urls

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I really don't get this.   I have the following 'get' request:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "api/getdirectories/",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function ( data ) {
        // Do stuff
    }
} );
```

This is in a page served up to me by my staging server, `http://atlas/Reporter`.  On my local dev box, this works, and in looking at fiddler I see the correct URL `http://localhost/Reporter/api/getdirectories`.  On the staging server however the request is to `http://atlas/api/getdirectories`, which is invalid and I get a 404 error.

Why is the 'Reporter' part of my path being dropped on the staging server?  In looking at the document, the URL, baseURI, documentURI are all `http://atlas/Reporter`, and the domain is `atlas`.  Exactly the same as on my local dev box (except it is all 'localhost' instead of 'atlas'.

This problem has plagued me for a while now.  I think I have it figured out and all is good, and then I run into it again.  I don't think it is a same origin policy issue, as I am requesting the data from the same site the page originated from.

So, how exactly is the full url determined for the request?  It doesn't seem to be one of the document variables mentioned above being concatenated onto my relative URL... so how does this work?

`Edit: Removed the '/' from the URL as it is distracting from the real issue- behavior is the same with or without it.`

Comment: Shouldn't your URL be `api/getdirectories/` instead of `/api/getdirectories/`?

Comment: have you attempted url: "api/getdirectories/",

Comment: I have tried `api/getdirectories`, same effect.

Comment: What's the path of your HTML file and what URL do you use int the browser to open it ?

Comment: @dystroy The correct path is `http://atlas/reporter/api/getdirectores`. This is a web.api application hosted on my server.

Comment: Sometime you write "Reporter", some other "reporter". Are you aware that some OS are case sensitive when looking for files ?

Comment: It's not looking for files- as I mentioned this is a web.api app, the content is generated by the web service.  This is IIS so is case insensitive.

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if this is related, but when jQuery ajax builds relative urls, it matters if the current page url ends with "/" or not

---

If you invoke a page without an ending `/`:

```
http://atlas/Reporter
```

the relative urls from ajax calls on that page are ignoring the last segment:

```
http://atlas/_relative_url_passed_to_ajax
```

---

If you end with `/`:

```
http://atlas/Reporter/
```

the relative urls are using the last path segment `Reporter`:

```
http://atlas/Reporter/_relative_url_passed_to_ajax
```

Answer (score 9):

`/` at the start of an URL makes it absolute.

You probably want a relative URL, that is

```
api/getdirectories/
```

or

```
getdirectories/
```

or

```
../api/getdirectories/
```

Comment: Regardless, the `Reporter` portion is missing.  In my case, the url ends up being the same (wrong) address.

Comment: What's the path of your HTML file and what URL do you use int the browser to open it ?

Comment: The correct path is `http://atlas/reporter/api/getdirectores`.  This is a web.api application hosted on my server.

Comment: This solved my problem--remove slash at the beginning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check the document_root on your server or if you have some virtual servers declared

Comment: This is interesting- except I dont know how to check this on my IIS server... where would I find it?

Comment: I looked into the IIS settings for my site- the only thing I saw was 'Virtual Path' in the Advanced Settings.  But this value is identical on my staging server and my local dev box.  :(

Comment: Sorry I dont know IIS, but there must be a configuration file somewhere... it is sure

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>tst</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Data list</h1>
      <table border="1" width="50%" id="tblData">
         <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'datas.txt',
                type:'post',
                datatype:'json',
                success:function(response){
                    var myDataBunch = $.parseJSON(response);
                    var txt = '';
                    for(var i=0; i<myDataBunch.length; i++){
                        txt+= '<tr><td>'+ myDataBunch[i].id +'</td><td>'+ myDataBunch[i].name +'</td><td>'+myDataBunch[i].location+'</td></tr>'
                    }
                    $('#tblData').append(txt);
                }
            })
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I thought I have fixed it since some of my AJAX URLs has already been working on relative URLs but I am quite perplexed why some of my AJAX calls are not working as expected. Here is the my first issue:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Controller/GetFiles',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (data) {
               //Business Logic Here
            },
            error: function (err) {
            },
        });
```

Originally my URL is `/Controller/GetFiles'`. But upon deploying it to staging site which requires relative URL, this will not work. So in order to fix it. I need to remove the `/` on my URL.

But later on I noticed that some of my URL with the same format is still not working. The solution? Add additional `/` on the end of my URL. Here is the ending format:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'Controller/GetFiles/',   
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (data) {
               //Business Logic Here
            },
            error: function (err) {
            },
        });
```