# AJAX: "The requested URL was not found on this server" on localhost

Tags: ajax

1. Ajax can contact the remote server nicely(uses jsonp) and beautiful data is returned.
2. In localhost it says that the url was not found on this server.
3. I 'alert' the url right before the ajax, copy-paste it into the browsers address bar, and beautiful data is returned.

WHY?

Oh why isn't my ajax working in localhost when the url clearly works?

I use WAMP-server and I've created an alias directory for the project folder. Like I said, the url works because I can go to it through the address bar of the browser, but ajax fails for some reason.

The code:

```
var temp_url = "localhost/api/1.1/app_dev.php/getsomething/something";
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    url: temp_url,
    timeout:5000, // 5 second timeout in millis!
    data:{ 'get_data' : querystring},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        console.debug(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception)
    {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: post your attempted code.

Comment: What server are you running locally? What does the config look like? What does your Ajax method look like? We can't help you unless you post the code that you're running.

Comment: @ajm Edited the Q. Anything else I can provide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we don't have access to, or sufficient information to replicate, your dev server, the best we can do is suggest a few things that might fix it. Here are the three most likely causes (from my experience):

1. **You're using a relative path instead of an absolute path.**
   It's possible, if your site is located at, say, `[localhost]/site/page.html`, that the AJAX request is being interpreted by your browser locally, since you used a relative path. So your actual request is possibly being sent to: `[localhost]/site/localhost/api/1.1/app_dev.php/getsomething/something`... This would also explain why you can copy & paste the URL from the `alert()`, since copying and pasting it into a URL bar automatically makes it an absolute path.

Solution: Try using an absolute path, like this:

```
var temp_url = "/api/1.1/app_dev.php/getsomething/something"
```

You can confirm the URL your app is requesting by checking the 'Network' panel in Dev Tools in either Chrome, Safari, or Firefox.

---

2. **The current URL you're on ends with a /.** See [the second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687907/ajax-and-relative-urls); AJAX is picky about whether the current URL you're on ends with a forward slash or not.

Solution: Either add, or remove the forward slash from your current page, if possible.

---

3. **Localhost might reject your request for CORS reasons.** This is probably not your issue at the moment, since you're reporting a 404 error, but be aware that often I've encountered localhost not allowing AJAX requests due to some arcane cross-domain origin policy, so this is a good thing to mention in case you do run into it soon.

Solution: See http://enable-cors.org. If that doesn't work, you'll need to spin up a server to run locally instead of relying on retrieving files from your filesystem.

Good luck!

Comment: My god... The first one actually worked! I never thought that the browser would do something that funny with the url, since it does have the "localhost" at the beginning. I didn't check the real error clearly before but now that I did, it does have the sites url at the beginning and after that the called url. Stupid browsers.. :D Thanks a bunch bro! Saved a whole lotta headache.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file you has created is having valid file Type like **PHP file** or just copy paste the existing valid working php file and write you ajax code in it. It will work now. **myAjax** file shown in below image is invalid file and **material** is valid PHP file[image]